# Telegram bot ends unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, http-proxy

Trying to make my first telegram bot, in all examples and instructions it looks very simple and easy to repeat. However, my bot doesn't work at all. Firstly, I am from Russia and telegram api is blocked, so I need to use proxy. Took one from https://www.socks-proxy.net/. Got token from BotFather. Now when I run my script `telegraf.js`:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const SocksAgent = require('socks5-https-client/lib/Agent');
const socksAgent = new SocksAgent({
   socksHost: '103.206.97.70',
   socksPort: 4145,
});
const bot = new Telegraf(MY_TOKEN, {
telegram: {
    agent: socksAgent,
}
});
bot.hears('hi', ctx => {
   return ctx.reply('Hey!');
});
bot.startPolling();
```

nothing happens and program finished[image].

[image]

I understand that problem is in my proxy configuration, but can't understand what exactly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in proxy. I used `https-proxy-agent` instead of `socks5-https-client`

```
import Telegraf from 'telegraf';
import config from 'config';
import HttpsProxyAgent from 'https-proxy-agent';

const TOKEN = config.get('token');
const proxy = config.get('proxy');

const bot = new Telegraf(TOKEN, {
    telegram: {
        agent: new HttpsProxyAgent({
            host: proxy.host,
            port: proxy.port
        })
    },
});

bot.hears('hi', ctx => {
    return ctx.reply('Hey!');
});
bot.startPolling();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')
const { SocksProxyAgent } = require('socks-proxy-agent');


const bot = new Telegraf('YOUR BOT API', {
    telegram: {
        agent: new SocksProxyAgent('socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050')
    },
});


bot.hears('hi', ctx => {
    return ctx.reply("HEY!");
});
bot.startPolling();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.